# Centering elements when printing

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage where all the content is centered using a wrapper div. It displays fine, but when it print the entire webpage becomes left-aligned. I want the page to be centered on the sheet.

Basically what I have is:

```
<div id="wrapper">
   Contents
</div>
```

The contents div is centered using CSS in the following way:

```
body{ width: 100%; margin: 0; }
#wrapper {width: 60%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }
```

Is there a way to make the page centered when printing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the same way. Just make sure that 'print' is included in [the media types](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html) specified for the stylesheet.